# Spring Boot and ActiveMQ: Ignores broker-url and uses default localhost:61616

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I'm using Spring Boot and ActiveMQ. In application.properties I set the url for activemq like this:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false
```

As you can see I'm using an embedded broker (dependency added in pom).
This is my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(
    basePackageClasses = {ServiceApplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class}
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ServletComponentScan
public class ServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

These are the activemq related dependencies in the pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <version>5.14.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have a single application.properties, I don't have different profiles.

But when I run the app, I get this log:

```
[ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
```

It's trying to connect to tcp://localhost:61616 even though that's not the url I defined.

I tried removing @EnableAutoConfiguration but still the same issue.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You must have some conflicting configuration settings elsewhere as the default is to use an in-memory broker with the URL `vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false`.

Comment: Are you using actvemq starter or just a dependency? Also make sure you do not run the wrong profile since it will get properties from other configuration files application-test.properties, application-dev.properties etc. Another reason could be system property that overrides the property in application.properties

Comment: Hi @AndyWilkinson I don't think the default is the in memory since it requires an extra dependency. I don't have any other setting in the project

Comment: Hi @DanyloZatorsky I just added the activemq dependencies I have in the post. I'm not using starter, and I have a single application.properties.  I also do not have any system property set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ActiveMQ client is not aware of `spring.activemq.broker-url` since this property is used to configure spring-boot-starter-activemq.If you do not have this starter - you configure nothing with this property.

I would suggest you to go through the following resources to have a better understanding of how to set up spring-boot-starter-activemq in your project:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html

Hope it helps!